# How to create a window handle from a method in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I built a C# windows form application and I am trying to load text to `toolstripsstatuslable` from a method. However, I called that method from another external thread and when I run it, it an error; seen below.

`Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

And this is my method.

```
public void loadNotification(string text)
{
    Invoke(new UpdateLabel(UpdateUI), text);
    statusStrip.Refresh();
}
```

and it will invoke to this method

```
private void UpdateUI(string labelText)
{
    MessageBox.Show("update ui");
    tssNotification.Text = labelText;
    //statusStrip.Refresh();
}
```

and this is my thread's `run()` method that is calling to the `loadNotification()` method

```
public void Run()
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("this is System Thread");
    m = new MainInterface();
    Notifications ne = new Notifications(m.loadNotification);
    ne.Invoke("aksdjasd");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I know that the problem is not creating a window handling and if I call this `loadNotification` method from `form_load` event it will work, but I have no chance to do that.

How could I solve this problem. Please help me?

Comment: "I have no chance to do that" is the kind of problem description that nobody could possibly help you with.  You must.

Comment: @HansPassant You mean, I must call the method from Form_load event? Is that so?

Comment: No, you must use the Load event to start the thread.  Doing it any sooner gets you this exception.

Comment: @HansPassant Form Load event or any other Load event?

Comment: The error tells you, that you're tryining to modify something which isn't there. So you have to wait until the control is created to modify it.